# Application is scaled twice on a high dpi monitor

Tags: c++, winapi, dpi

I am developing a dpi-aware winapi application and I ran into a problem that its window is scaled twice for no reason. It seems that dpi scaling is applied twice after the application window is created. Here's my code.
First I make my application dpi-aware:

```
::SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE);
```

Then I calculate dpi scale of my monitor and create a 500 by 500 window considering this scale:

```
dpiScale = <get dpi scale using ::GetDpiForMonitor()> / 96.f;
hWnd = ::CreateWindow(..., 0, 0, 500 * dpiScale, 500 * dpiScale, ...);
```

I also want my window minimum size to be 500 by 500:

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
{
    MINMAXINFO* info = (MINMAXINFO*)lParam;
    info->ptMinTrackSize.x = 500 * dpiScale;
    info->ptMinTrackSize.y = 500 * dpiScale;
    break;
}
```

Then I implement dpi changed event handling:

```
case WM_DPICHANGED:
{
    dpiScale = LOWORD(wParam) / 96.f;
    RECT rect = *(RECT *)lParam;
    ::SetWindowPos(... rect ...);
    break;
}
```

When I launch my application on a monitor with high dpi, e.g. 120 (x1.25 scale factor) the application window looks bigger than it should be. I also tried printing out window size on each `WM_SIZE` message:

```
case WM_SIZE:
{
    RECT r;
    ::GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);
    int width = (r.right - r.left);
    int height = (r.bottom - r.top);
    std::cout << "WM_SIZE " << width << " " << height << " scale factor: " << (width / 500.f) << std::endl;
    break;
}
```

and here's what I get:

```
WM_SIZE 625 625 scale factor: 1.25
WM_SIZE 781 781 scale factor: 1.562
```

Note that there are only two places where I apply dpi scaling manually - windows creation and `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message handling. I also tried removing dpi scaling from `::CreateWindow()` call and it did not change anything.

It looks like Windows is resizing my window automatically although I've set dpi awareness for my application. Why does this happen? How can I get around this? Thank you.

**UPDATED:**

I've created a minimal reproducible example which can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/APodlinny/179b90b9e0d45ea9576d33dca2273dce
You can either use MSVC project files from the gist or create an empty Win32 MSVC project, add `main.cpp` source file and ensure that:
* Windows SDK 8.1 or newer is used (check VC directories in project settings, namely include and library directories)
* `shcore.lib` library is in linker additional dependencies
* Linker subsystem is `Console`

> Maybe in Windows 10 high dpi scaling is on for the application?

I doubt that because I explicitly set dpi awareness for my application in the beginning of the `_tWinMain(...)` function. "Override dpi scaling" option in compatibility settings for the app is also unchecked. In addition the window content itself does not seem to be scaled either.

> Is there a difference in scaling between the primary monitor and the one your app is on?

Yes, but I don't think that it matters. I have two monitors and I've tested my application in two configurations:
1. Secondary 125%, primary 100%, window is created on the secondary monitor.
2. Secondary 125%, primary 125%, window is created on the primary monitor.
In both cases the window is scaled twice.

> Bug is in some other code. Put breakpoint on `::GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);` in `WM_SIZE` handler. Start debuger, when it stops on breakpoint allow it to run again. When it stops second time inspect call stack to find origin of the second `WM_SIZE`.

Thanks for the hint! It appeared that the second `WM_SIZE` message is caused by the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message sent by Windows:

```
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
{
    WINDOWPOS* pos = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam;
    std::cout << "WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED " << pos->x << " " << pos->y << " " << pos->cx << " " << pos->cy << std::endl;
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

```
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED 100 100 625 625
WM_SIZE 625 625 scale factor: 1.25
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED 100 100 781 781
WM_SIZE 781 781 scale factor: 1.562
```

The first `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`/`WM_SIZE` pair is caused by the `::ShowWindow()` call, the second one can be traced to `::GetMessage()`, but I have no idea what is causing these messages to be sent.

Comment: Maybe in Windows 10 high dpi scaling is on for the application?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Is there a difference in scaling between the primary monitor and the one your app is on?  See remarks with the [MINMAXINFO documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-minmaxinfo).

Comment: Just guessing here. Maybe some settings are cached. Log off and log back in with the same DPI settings to reset.

Comment: Bug is in some other code. Put breakpoint on `::GetWindowRect(hWnd, &r);` in `WM_SIZE` handler. Start debuger, when it stops on breakpoint allow it to run again. When it stops second time inspect call stack to find origin of the second `WM_SIZE`.

Comment: Thank you for some useful hints! I've updated the question and added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @binzo First I can't reproduce the issue that "dpi scaling is applied twice after the application window is created", for me only once WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED/WM_SIZE pair received. I test on one monitor with scale factor set to 100% and 125%. Windows 10 1903. Can you have a try to see if you can reproduce the issue in this way? What's your Window version?

Comment: @binzo [UWP applications automatically—and dynamically—scale for each display that they're running on.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) So I create a UWP app with a 500x500 button, it will become lager when I change scale factor from 100% to 125%. So "the application window looks bigger" seems expected.